# Kendo Data Grid Angular upgrade 14 issue

Tags: angular, rxjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datetimepicker

i am using kendo grid for Angular. I saw below error while loading data in kendo grid after upgrading to Angular 14 using below packages in package.json. Please let me know if this is package version issues.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
    at ListComponent.ngOnInit (index.js:11229:28)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2491:22)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2460:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2411:9)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.mjs:9854:17)
    at Module.ɵɵadvance (core.mjs:9837:5)
    at GridComponent_ng_template_5_Template (index.js:154:5)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:12113:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:11998:13)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:13026

Package.json -

    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-file-saver": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "latest",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
```

Comment: Did anyone got solution for this. After upgrading Ang13 I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

the error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add') at ListComponent.ngOnInit (index.js:11229:28) ...` says what's wrong. Just go to `ListComponent` to its `ngOnInit` method and check whe you use `add` (method/property) and why its "owner" is `undefined`. After upgrading some flow or naming can change and cause such a problem.

Comment: Thanks Ricudo for the response. But ListComponent method mentioned in the error was related to index.js file of node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid. This is not related to my application method.

Comment: Oh. In such a case I think you don't have many options. Sometimes after update you can meet unexpected issues because of old cache. Just stop all runs, remove `.angular` folder and run again. Also in the error I see line `GridComponent_ng_template_5_Template`, so check all the templates you pass to the `GridComponent` (if you pass ones). And if the issue is really with the library, you can exlore their source code ([link]https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/installation/source-code/) and create issue on their github (they already have 1.1k ones) maybe even yours is already there

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade RxJs version to **6.5.3**

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess I already tried this but I will check again.